How to make custom SwiftUI views appear in the Xcode library using LibraryContentProvider?
I'm trying to add my own SwiftUI view to the Xcode library in Xcode 16.
However, the view does not appear in the library.
Does anybody have a hint, what could be missing?
Searching for the topic brings up a couple of blog posts with similar code, however, neither works for me. Tried Xcode 16.0, 16.1, 15.4.

Apple's WWDC Video on the topic: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10649/
Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertoolssupport/librarycontentprovider

My test code:
import DeveloperToolsSupport
import SwiftUI

protocol LibraryContentProvider {
    @LibraryContentBuilder
    var views: [LibraryItem] { get }
    
    // Do that later...
    /*
    @LibraryContentBuilder
    func modifiers(base: Custom1View) -> [LibraryItem] {
        []
    }
     */
}

struct CustomView: View {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .bold()
            Text(message)
        }
        .padding(8)
        .border(.gray, width: 2)
    }
}

struct MyLibraryContent: LibraryContentProvider {
    @LibraryContentBuilder
    var views: [LibraryItem] {
        LibraryItem(
            CustomView(title: "title1", message: "message1"),
            title: "Custom Title"
        )
    }
}


Do not redeclare the LibraryContentProvider protocol. Remove that protocol declaration and it should work fine.

@Sweeper Thanks! If you provide an answer, I'll accept it

Regarding the downvotes: I made the first mistake of starting with the wrong sample code taken from some of the search results and made the second mistake of not cleaning up properly between tests. In my opinion the hint for the protocol is helpful information. (Of course I have to live with the embarrassment of not seeing it myself :-) )
